# Logarithm value difference between calculator and table

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

[image]

Look at the example given at the bottom of the attached table. Log(0.003674) = -3.5652.
I understand how this is procured from the log table.

But if you use a calculator and plug in the numbers directly, you get log(0.003674) = -2.4348.

Why is there such a discrepancy? I'm really stumped on this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand this notation.$$\overline{3}.5652=(-3)+0.5652=-2.4348$$

Comment: See also [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline%23Negative) Wiki reference.

Answer (score 2):

$\log(3.674\cdot10^{-3})=\log(3.674)-3=0.5652-3 = -2.4348$ The notation $\bar{3}.4348$ doesn't mean $-3.4348$ but $0.4348-3$, it is correct, they only use a notation which you aren't familiar with. There should be some kind of notes about notation is the tables as well.